# Writing huge processed text into a file from MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic-9

I have very huge processed text content(content process is done using XQuery in MarkLogic server), which I need to write into a text/csv file(outside of MarkLogic server). When I use standard API function like `xdmp:save()` it is consuming almost 4-5 min of the time. What is the best and idle way to reduce content writing time?

Comment: Don't say "huge", tell us the actual size.

Comment: please clarify a few MarkLogic related questions (1) is the content stored in individual documents-per-record ?  (2) since the the goal is tabular data (csv), have you used TDE to model the data into the rows index?

Answer (score 0):

If timeouts are an issue, you can always extend the timeout limit up to the configured max using [xdmp:request-set-time-limit](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-request-time-limit)

Instead of writing the output directly to a file on the MarkLogic filesystem, why not expose that query as an endpoint and have the client retrieve the contents?

- either returned directly as they execute that module
- or save the document into the database and return the URI that they can use to fetch via [GET /v1/documents](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents)?

Another option for generating giant CSV reports would be to leverage tools such as [CoRB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) to execute a batch job and collect the results in a CSV file.

https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/Hello-World-from-CORB